# select rows that value is less than 50% of sum grouped value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe subdata:

```
PageId  VolumePred  ConversionPred  OSBrowser
1005581    8.0            7.0       (11, 16)
1016529  175.0           85.0       (11, 16)
1016529    4.0            4.0       (11, 17)
1016529    4.0            4.0       (12, 14)
1016529   29.0           19.0       (12, 16)
```

For each OSBrowser I select only "PageId" that the cumulated value of "VolumePred" is less than 44.

Here the code that works correctly :

```
h = subdata.groupby(["PageId", "OSBrowser"]).sum().reset_index().sort_values(["OSBrowser","ConversionPred"],ascending=[True,False])
output = h[h.groupby("OSBrowser")["VolumePred"].transform("cumsum").lt(44)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

But now I would like to change the 44 value by the 50% of the value of (sum of VolumePred for each "OSBrowser")

for example the expected output for subdata is an empty dataframe because for (11, 16) OSBrowser  : the (11, 16) of two records are bigger than (0.5* (175+8)).. same thing for the others rows

Any idea please? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or like this?

```py
h = subdata.groupby(["PageId", "OSBrowser"]).sum()\
    .reset_index()\
    .sort_values(['OSBrowser','ConversionPred'],ascending=[True,False])
h['VolumePred_total'] = h.groupby("OSBrowser")["VolumePred"].transform("sum")
output = h[h.groupby("OSBrowser")["VolumePred"].transform("cumsum").lt(h['VolumePred_total']*0.5)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: My english isn't good to give a high quality answer, this may take some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```py
h = subdata.groupby(["PageId", "OSBrowser"]).sum()\
    .reset_index()\
    .sort_values(['OSBrowser','ConversionPred'],ascending=[True,False])
VolumePred_total = h.groupby('OSBrowser').sum()["VolumePred"].rename('VolumePred_total')
h1 = h.merge(VolumePred_total,on='OSBrowser')
output = h1[h1.groupby("OSBrowser")["VolumePred"].transform("cumsum")\
    .lt(h1["VolumePred_total"]*0.5)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but it does not work, I got an empty result dataframe because VolumePred_y column is NaN value

Comment: I changed the answer.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Sorry! My english isn't good to give a high quality answer.

Comment: @z-ali no problem :) you gave me the solution and it is more than fine ):